# How to test generator based flow-control in JavaScript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, generator

How can I make Mocha wait until asynchronous functions finish?

### Module

```
var fs = require('mz/fs');
var co = require('co');

module.exports = new filecache();

function filecache () {
  var self = this;
  var storage = storage || {};

  self.cache = co(function* (filePath, fileName) {
    if (yield fs.exists(filePath)) {
      storage[fileName] = yield fs.readFile(filePath);
    }
  });

  self.has = function has (fileName) {
    return storage.hasOwnProperty(fileName);
  };
}
```

### Test (Mocha)

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('phialcash', function () {
  var filecache;
  var filePath;
  var fileName;

  beforeEach(function () {
    filecache = require('..');
    filePath = './tests/file.fixture.txt';
    fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();
  });

  describe('#exists', function () {
    it('returns true if a file exists in the cache', function () {
      filecache.cache(filePath, fileName);

      expect(filecache.has(fileName)).to.equal(true);
    });
  });
});
```

The test fails because `filecache.cache(filePath, fileName);` executes asynchronously so `filecache.has(fileName)` is still false when the expectation is run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `co` at the site of the method call and not in the definition.

```
self.cache = function* (filePath, fileName) {
    if (yield fs.exists(filePath)) {
      storage[fileName] = yield fs.readFile(filePath);
    }
};
```

When testing, mark the function as asynchronous and pass `done` to the co-routine. `co` will invoke the `done` callback with arguments `done(err, response)`. Any exceptions thrown in the asynchronous call or failed `expect`ations will cause the test case to fail.

```
describe('#exists', function () {
    it('returns true if a file exists in the cache', function (done) {
      co(function * () {
        yield *filecache.cache(filePath, fileName); //generator delegation.
        expect(filecache.has(fileName)).to.equal(true);
      })(done);

    });
  });
```

This is an excerpt from an application that uses `koa`, which internally uses `co` to handle control flow. All of the statements that are `yield`ed to are asynchronous calls that return `thunks`.

```
group.remove = function * (ids) {
        var c3Domain = this.c3Domain;

        let deletedCount = yield this.baseRemove(ids);
        if(deletedCount > 0) {
            let deletedGroupMappings = yield [this.connection.query(UNMAP_GROUPS, [this.c3Id, ids]), this.tag.unmapGroupTags(ids)];
            let deletedQueueCount = yield this.removeQueuesFromXml(ids);
            if(deletedQueueCount > 0) {
                let eslCommands = ['reloadxml'].concat(ids.map(function (id) {
                    return ['callcenter_config queue unload', id + '@' + c3Domain];
                }));
                yield this.esl.multiApi(eslCommands);  
            }
        }
        return deletedCount;
    };
```

Test case:

```
it('should delete group', function (done) {
    co(function *() {
        let count = yield group.remove(['2000'])
        assert(count === 1)
    })(done)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to wrap my head around generators. Can you breafly explain why `You should use co at the site of the method call and not in the definition.`?

Comment: Because your version of `self.cache` returns a function that takes in a callback as its last argument. To run your tests, you'll have to use: `fileCache.cache(filePath, fileName, function () { assert(fileCache.has(fileName)); });` This can be done without using generators and `co`. If you were using `koa`, which uses `co`, the alternate approach lets you use constructs of the form: `app.get('/:file', function * () { yield fileCache.cache(filePath, this.params.file); this.body = fileCache.get(this.params.file);} );`